# bind tmux prefix key to option-a

Tags: tmux

I currently have my prefix key as

`set-option -g prefix C-a`

However, I want to change it from the `C` or `control` key to the `option` key which sits directly to the right of the `control` key. It's easier for my thumb to reach. I do not know the key for `option`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in your terminal, go to `Preferences` -> `keyboard` -> checkmark `Use Option As Meta`

Then in your tmux config use the following...

```
set-option -g prefix M-a
```